# OpenLiteSpeed WordPress VPS 404 Error on Non-Wordpress Site Install in Sub Folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, openlitespeed

I have an OpenLiteSpeed VPS WordPress install over at Vultr, and am trying to install a non-WordPress website into a sub-folder I created.

Ex.) https://example.com/test that is pointed to a new folder I created in the WordPress root install directory of `/var/www/html/test`

I created the directory and placed the files needed there that include an `index.php` file, however when I go to https://example.com/test, I receive a 404 Not Found error. I believe it has something to do with modifying the .htaccess file in the root of my WordPress install, but am unsure of what to modify 100%.

Any help is appreciated!

I tried modifying the Rewrite rules but am not confident in the options I chose. I since reverted the .htaccess file back to my default settings in which OpenLiteSpeed defines.

Comment: "I believe it has something to do with modifying the .htaccess file in the root of my WordPress install" - You shouldn't need to modify the root (WordPress) `.htaccess` file at all? How have you modified this file and why?

Comment: @MrWhite - I did NOT modify the .htaccess file, at all, I was just pointing out that in order to get the subfolder to be recognized I believe I HAVE to modify the .htaccess file to get around the 404 errors. That is my assumption. Any tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This can be closed out - I have it defined in my index.php file that resides in that folder point to a database I created in phpMyAdmin and I had the database field filled out incorrectly. Thank you to everyone who replied though. Oops!